# Calc. 3 TNB; Find the Normal Vector

Tags: calculus

**Question:** Suppose a curve C is parametrized by the vector function $\vec{r(t)}$ on $-1 < t < 1$, and $\vec{r(0)} = \vec{0}$ and $\vec{r'(0)} = <2,0,0> $ and $\vec{r''(0)} = <2,2,2>$

Find its unit normal vector $\hat{N}$ at $t = 0$

The given solution is:

$\hat{N}$ is orthogonal to $\hat{T}$, and $\vec{r''(0)}$ is spanned by $\hat{T}$ and $\hat{N}$ that $\vec{r''(0)} = a\hat{T}+b\hat{N}, b > 0$ and since $\vec{r''(0)} = a\hat{T}+b\hat{N} =<2,0,0> + <0,2,2>$, we get $\hat{N}=(1\div\sqrt2)(<0,1,1>)$

I don't understand how the solution arrive at the Normal vector, I will appreciate it very much if anyone can elaborate on how to solve this problem. And is there other techniques to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wrote $\textbf{r}''(0)$ as a linear combination of $\textbf{T}$ and $\textbf{N}$ so that $a,b$ scale them (since $\textbf{T},\textbf{N}$ are unit vectors), then found $a\textbf{T}=\textbf{r}'(0)$ and subtracted it from $\textbf{r}''(0)$ to get $b\textbf{N}$, and subsequently multiplied by $\frac{1}{b}$ to obtain $\textbf{N}$.